# Malformed html error thrown from html based object in appscript

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I've hit a wall on an issue when I try to display the content.text object in apps script, it returns a malformed html error specifically regarding my fetch to a GET request of

```
https://www.cloudconnect.xxx...
```

I get everything I need, but the content.text bit which is throwing a malformed html error in apps script. I'd like to use the html and return the documents as is with proper formatting and believe that I can properly parse this html to apps script using htmloutput as it needs to be sanitized, but I believe it's what's throwing the malformed html object. How can I proceed without escaping html characters? How can I properly parse this? Has anyone been successful at this by any chance?

Example of content.text:

```
<body>
    <!-- [DocumentBodyStart:a63392fa-f859-4513-867e-1f3d2714b006] -->
    <div class=\"jive-rendered-content\">
        <p>Hi,team!</p>
        <p style=\"min-height: 8pt; padding: 0px;\">&#160;</p>
        <p>When executing attest () of SafetyNet Attestation API, apkPackageName is obtained as a parameter.</p>
        <p>I ran this API several times.</p>
        <p>As a result, the apkPackageName parameter was missing only once.</p>
        <p>In all other execution results, the parameter apkPackageName is present and will not occur again.</p>
        <p style=\"min-height: 8pt; padding: 0px;\">&#160;</p>
        <p>Why can't I get the apkPackageName when running the SafetyNet Attestation API on a device that has not been
            tampered with?</p>
        <p style=\"min-height: 8pt; padding: 0px;\">&#160;</p>
        <p>device : Kyocera 704KC</p>
        <p style=\"min-height: 8pt; padding: 0px;\">&#160;</p>
        <p>Regards,</p>
    </div><!-- [DocumentBodyEnd:a63392fa-f859-4513-867e-1f3d2714b006] -->
</body>
```

Would anyone have any pointers on how to proceed from here? My goal is to obtain the text from the content.text object, which I can see on any regular editor, but not in apps script for some reason while using the html format that it returns as is.

Code.gs

```
function doGet(request) { 
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate();
}

function include(filename) { 
  var finalRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.cloudconnect.xxx...');

  var data = finalRequest.toString().replace("throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';", "").trim(); 

  data = JSON.parse(data);

  var returnedData = [];

  for(var i in data.list){
    var content = data.list[i];
    var content_subject = JSON.stringify(content.subject);
    var content_text = JSON.stringify(content.content.text);
    returnedData.push(content_subject + "<br />" + "<br />" + textBody(content_text));
  }
  return returnedData;
}

function textBody(content){ // <-- where the error throws on the content_text object
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(content);
}

var entityMap = {
  '&': '&amp;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#39;',
  '/': '&#x2F;',
  '`': '&#x60;',
  '=': '&#x3D;'
};

function escapeHtml(string) {
  return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'`=\/]/g, function (s) {
    return entityMap[s];
  });
}

function myFunction() {
  Logger.log(HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .getCode());
}
```

Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
   <body>
  <script>
  var responseSubject;
  var responseContent;
    function displayData(responseSubject, responseContent) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = responseSubject + <br> + responseContent + <br>;
    } 
    google.script.run.withFailureHandler(displayData).withSuccessHandler(displayData).include();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Update***

I have hit a wall returning the Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 21, file "Code")

Code.gs

```
function doGet(request) { 
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate();
}

function include(filename) { 
  var finalRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.cloudconnect.xxx....');

  var data = finalRequest.toString().replace("throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';", "").trim(); 

  data = JSON.parse(data);

  var returnedData = [];

  for(var i in data.list){
    var content = data.list[i];
    var contentSubject = JSON.stringify(content.subject);
    var contentText = JSON.stringify(content.content.text);
    returnedData.push(contentSubject + "<br/>" + "<br/>");
    var fixedContent = escapeHtml(contentText);// fixes the malformed Html error
    var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(fixedContent);//the attempt to read the onlick event and load the content text - but it throws the error: Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 21, file "Code")
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui);
    Logger.log("returnedData is: " + returnedData);
  }
  return returnedData;
}

var entityMap = {
  '&': '&amp;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#39;',
  '/': '&#x2F;',
  '`': '&#x60;',
  '=': '&#x3D;'
};

function escapeHtml(string) {
  return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'`=\/]/g, function (s) {
    return entityMap[s];
  });
}

function myFunction() {
  Logger.log(HtmlService
             .createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .getCode());
}

//function contentBody(responseContent){ <-- realized I can't do this from a custom function
  //var html = responseContent;
  //var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui); 
//}
```

Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
    <script>
    var responseSubject;
    var responseContent;

    function displaySubjects(responseSubject) {
        document.getElementById('output').addEventListener('click', getContentBody).innerHTML = responseSubject;
    } 
    google.script.run.withFailureHandler(displaySubjects).withSuccessHandler(displaySubjects).include();

    //function displayContentText(responseContent){
        //document.getElementById('projection').innerHTML = responseContent;
    //}
    //google.script.run.withFailureHandler(displayContentText).withSuccessHandler(displayContentText).contentBody();
    </script>
  </head>
   <body>
    <p id = "output"></p>
    <p id = "projection"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

My goal here is to add a click listener to the subjects and have them load the content text through the Html service.

Any help would be highly appreciated please.

Cheers!

Comment: Is there any reason that you are escaping your double quotes in your HTML `content.text`? Could you add the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I used this escapeHtml function at first, but don't use it now. I initially used it for the subjects object but didn't need it.

Comment: Hey Raserhin, the error that returns is: Exception: Malformed HTML content: "<body><!-- [DocumentBodyStart:c062b27a-e734-42fb-a146-c2d978fb77da] --><div class=\"jive-rendered-content\"></div><!-- [DocumentBodyEnd:c062b27a-e734-42fb-a146-c2d978fb77da] --></body>". (line 21, file "Code")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
function htmltest() {
  var html='<body><!--[DocumentBodyStart:a63392fa-f859-4513-867e-1f3d2714b006]--><div class="jive-rendered-content"><p>Hi,team!</p><p style="min-height:8pt;padding:0px;">&#160;</p><p>When executing at test() of Safety NetAttestationAPI, apkPackageName is obtained as a parameter.</p><p>I ran this API several times.</p><p>As a result,the apkPackageName parameter was missing only once.</p><p>In all other execution results,the parameter apkPackageName is present and will not occur again.</p><p style="min-height:8pt;padding:0px;">&#160;</p><p>Whycan\'t I get the apkPackageName when running the Safety NetAttestation API on a device that has not been tampered with?</p><p style="min-height:8pt;padding:0px;">&#160;</p><p>device:Kyocera704KC</p><p style="min-height:8pt;padding:0px;">&#160;</p><p>Regards,</p></div><!--[DocumentBodyEnd:a63392fa-f859-4513-867e-1f3d2714b006]--></body>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setHeight(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "HTML Test");
}
```

Here's what I get when I run it just that way it is.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't the call to HtmlService.createHtmlOutput is what returns: Exception: Malformed HTML content: "<body><!-- [DocumentBodyStart:c062b27a-e734-42fb-a146-c2d978fb77da] --><div class=\"jive-rendered-content\"></div><!-- [DocumentBodyEnd:c062b27a-e734-42fb-a146-c2d978fb77da] --></body>". (line 21, file "Code")

Comment: When I run it, just as I have it written.  It works as shown in the dialog.  Perhaps you don't realize that edited all of the errors out of the string.  The old string does not work at all.

Comment: I'm curious how you got this to work...I've updated my code with your suggestion and I return the 'Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 21, file "Code")' ...it makes sense, just not sure how to proceed here.

Comment: Which line is line 21?

Comment: Hey Cooper! Line 21 is the call to:  "SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui);"

Comment: Well just to be sure I just took that function in my answer and pasted it into a script editor and ran it and the dialog popped up on the spreadsheet with that message on it.  I have already edited all of the malformed html out of the html string.

Comment: With the Exception message? I'm running this in apps script and that's what I return as well.

Comment: No exception message.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep messing around with this and see what comes of it, thank you so much for your help here.

Comment: I just moved to another account and open up an arbitrary spreadsheet and the editor pasted it in and ran it and got the dialog with the message and no errors.  Why don't you try it in another spreadsheet.